# ERC223 gas savings?

Tags: gas, erc-223

I was curious after reading this article how ERC-223 protocol for token accomplishes this:
[ERC20 vs ERC223. List of differences](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17054/erc20-vs-erc223-list-of-differences)

Energy savings. The transfer of ERC-223 tokens to a contract is a one step process rather than 2 step process (for ERC-20), and this means 2 times less gas and no extra blockchain bloating.

----------------------->

How does ERC-223 accomplish in one step subtracting the value from the sender and then add the value to the receiver?

Answer (score 2):

If the recipient is a contract it invokes a callback function after making the transfer of tokens

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _amount, bytes _data) public {

    // Standard transfer
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);

    // If recipient is a contract invoke token callback function
    if (isContract(_to)) {

        // Cast to interface
        TokenRecipient(_to).tokenFallback(msg.sender, _amount, _data);
    }

    // Notify event
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount, _data)
}
```

The `TokenRecipient` is a simple interface contract

```
contract TokenRecipient {
    function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _amount, bytes _data) public;
};
```

In case of doubts read [the recommended implementation](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard/tree/Recommended).

---

Having a single call should use less gas than two but I doub't you will reduce your gas cost in half, usually the `approve` call is cheap and is the only thing you will save.

One important benefit is you gain atomicity of the operations. With ERC-20 at least two steps are required to interact with a contract which can lead to a race condition, if the second operation fails you have to undo the approve which will be a third transaction. But with an ERC-223 token those two steps are atomic, if one of those fails the whole transaction is reversed.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael! So if I understand correctly, ERC223 transfer to contract consumes half as much gas as ERC20 approve and transferFrom at receiver contract.

Comment: So for transfer of token there's only one function call for Transfer in ERC223 instead of two function calls in ER20?

Comment: @golddigger I think the gas consumption will be lower but only very modest. The extra suppressed call to `approve` is usually cheap.