# Can I bypass the "approval" mechanism for tokens within my own ecosystem?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, erc-20-approve

Let's say I have my own ERC20 token `FOO`.

I'd like my users to be able to send their `FOO` to my smart contract `FooSwap`.

Is it acceptable practice to bypass the approval mechanism in the ERC20 `Foo` contract for transfers to the `FooSwap` contract address? If so, can I simply include a conditional on the transfer function that checks if the destination address is the `FooSwap` address, or could this open up vulnerabilities?

Comment: Well it can be done for sure but you have to keep mind that (1) you would be straying away from the ERC-20 standard and (2) your users will have to pay gas for this conditional check on every transfer.

Comment: Potentially related: [Is it possible to batch approve + transfer an ERC-20 token?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79653/is-it-possible-to-batch-approve-transfer-an-erc-20-token)