# how to call Transferfrom usdt contract?

Tags: erc-20

I am newbie, I am testing . I have 1 question. How to withdraw usdt from an approved spender?. We hope to receive an answer[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to withdraw it is by using the etherscan(or the relevant explorer itself).
[image: Goreli USDT]

As the token contract is verified you can use the write functions which is exposed through the explorer to withdraw the token.

When you are in the write contract tab, connect the wallet, fill up the data and execute.

from : spender's address
to : your address
value : the approved amount

Comment: Thank you sir , I see some contracts automatically withdraw without manual steps . Can you send me an article about this. Have a nice day.

Comment: if you referring to do the approval and the transferFrom in one transaction, it is not possible. If you are the owner you can just transfer the tokens directly to another account without approvals. 
refer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79653/is-it-possible-to-batch-approve-transfer-an-erc-20-token

Comment: Thank you, I mean create a smart contract, automatically call transferFrom

Comment: you can not program a smart contract to do something automatically when an event occurred. but it is possible offchain using something like JavaScript and listening to log events. these will be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488069/ethers-js-transferring-erc20-between-contracts
                                                   -                   
https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-solidity-events-2801d6a99a92

Comment: thanks you, love you