# Which contract should execute the approveAndTransferFrom function under one transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, transfer, erc-20-approve, transferfrom

I'm trying to perform approve and transfer under one tx but I don't understand which contract should be calling the `approveAndTransferFrom` function? Say contract A is trying to transfer tokens to contract B, so should contract A call the function? I also referred to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70187/is-it-possible-to-make-approve-and-transferfrom-in-single-transaction) but it doesn't say also.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract TokenTransferContract {
    // Reference to the ERC-20 token contract
    IERC20 private token;

    // Event to log successful transfer
    event TransferApprovedAndExecuted(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    // Constructor to set the ERC-20 token contract address
    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    // Function to approve and transfer tokens in a single transaction
    function approveAndTransferFrom(address _spender, address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
        // Approve the spender to spend tokens on behalf of the contract
        token.approve(_spender, _amount);

        // Transfer tokens from the contract to the specified address
        token.transferFrom(address(this), _to, _amount);

        // Emit an event to log the successful transfer
        emit TransferApprovedAndExecuted(address(this), _to, _amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As only the owner of the tokens can approve the spending of their tokens, yes it should be Contract A that call the `approveAndTransferFrom` function, with the spender being the `TokenTransferContract` contract.

However it seems like a bad idea because it would results in the same result as if Contract A simply transferred the tokens directly to Contract B but with higher gas cost.

If your goal is do both operations in a single transaction, you might want to check out this thread: [Is it possible to make approve and transferfrom in single transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70187/is-it-possible-to-make-approve-and-transferfrom-in-single-transaction)

Comment: Yeah, I already referred that thread in my question.