# How can we detect if tokens are transferred to our smart contract and avoid "allow"?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, erc-20, wallet-transfer, erc-223

Imagine you have a smart contract that accepts all forms of ERC20s. You want users to call a function by which they will send you their ERC20s and in exchange receive a greeting.

Technically we can do that by implementing the famous:

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
```

The problem with transferFrom is that it requires the user to first call

```
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
```

How can we avoid the approve part? I can see that someone proposes [ERC223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) but I'm not sure how that would help and it's unclear. I was thinking at wallets like MetaMask and how they handle token transfers but I think they just call `transfer();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of ERC20.

When Alice pays Bob, she sends a transaction to the token contract to make an accounting entry. There is no standard method for the token contract to inform Bob.

The allow/transferFrom flow resolves it with a 2-step process - first authorize Bob to take from Alice, then inform Bob. Since Bob is in the loop, Bob can do what Bob does.

ERC223 is a 1-step solution. Upon receipt of a transfer instruction, check if Bob is a contract. If so, invoke Bob's tokenFallback function so Bob can do whatever Bob does when certain tokens are received.

ERC223 is backward compatible with ERC20.

The receiving contract (store, exchange, service) should implement a tokenFallback() function. It will run when tokens are received. Sender pays for gas.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm nearly ready to accept your solution, I just want more details because I feel like I'm missing some points. You say that ERC223 is the 1-step solution but I don't fully understand how. Is there a reference to some practical code that I can see as an example?

Comment: I found something ( https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31643/erc223-gas-savings ) but I don't understand if the ERC223 would be a 1-step solution for ERC20s as well

Comment: No, it is not. You can make a contract that runs a tokenFallback function whenever an ERC223 token is received. Most contracts are concerned with 1 utility/payment/app token only and wouldn't know what to do with other types. ERC223 provides a method to reject unwanted ERC223 but it does not catch unwanted ERC20.

Answer (score 2):

ERC20 as defined [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) has a function called `approveAndCall` this allows to make the two steps in a single transaction. The function is:

```
function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes memory data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, address(this), data);
        return true;
    }
```

This allows a user to approve a number of tokens and call your contract (spender) in the same transaction. This will allows you to then call `transferFrom` within the same transaction. Your contract must have implemented a function to receive the call, as shown in the standard ERC20 token:

```
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes memory data) public;
}
```

This means you need to implement your logic inside a function called `receiveApproval` as described above.

Like this, your token is still ERC20 compatible.

The limitation here is that this function (`approveAndCall`) is optional, and not all tokens implement it and if you are planning to accept tokens that already exist, you need to verify that they have implemented the function `approveAndCall`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "ERC20 standard ... [has] a function called `approveAndCall`..." Correction, that function is not part of the ERC20 standard.

Comment: @Smarx, in the ethereum wiki, the link is in the answer, is titled "ERC20 token standard" and that is what I am referring as ERC20 standard.

Comment: Okay, but that's not the ERC20 standard. That's just a page on some wiki. The ERC20 standard is here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md.

Comment: thanks, I will update the answer to clarify that the wiki is not the standard.