# Gas and transaction fee confusion

Tags: transactions, tokens

First, I'm brand new to the Ethereum platform, and I'm simply trying to learn how the platform works at the moment, so I do apologise if any of the following is considered stupid questions. Now, here goes anyways

1. Is there any way of centrally funding a contract? So, if you have a smart contract, it can fund transactions of a certain type of token. So, for example, if I got a token I want to be free to move around, between wallets, the idea would be that the transaction fees where funded centrally.
2. Is it possible to mine transactions for a particular class of token? So, say, if I had a token, and I set the gas extremely low to keep costs down, could I then set up miners only mining that type of token?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it's always the transaction sender paying the transaction fees for now.
2. Miners "always" prioritize the Transactions that gives them the highes rewards. So if you set the gas price too low, your transaction will probbably not included in a block anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you creating an ethereum token using ERC-223 instead ERC-20, it will mostly save ETH on user and contract side.

Here for advantage:

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17071/19037

You could mae the contract refund eth from it's internal but that would be more costly and not very clever way to archieve what you are trying todo.

Maybe also take a look to custom ethereum network, where you could set a different gas value.