# Approve and Swap/Deposit at the same time

Tags: solidity, erc-20-approve

So one of the most annoying things for me is having to Approve before calling Swap or Deposit.

I would love there to be a proxy contract which just calls Approve and Swap/Deposit in the same function.

Are there any existing contracts that implement this already?

Comment: As said by other it is not possible with non-contract wallet. But it should be possible if the wallet is a contract.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done as far as I know.

`approve()` has to be called on the token contract **from the address holding the tokens**. Therefore, a contract could not call the approve function on behalf of your address.

Comment: Is that true even with delegatecall?

Comment: Yes see that other answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59936/42354